# How to calculate moments of a distribution specified by x, y coordinates

Tags: r

Imagine I have a simple dataframe of x, y coordinates.

```
dta_example <- data.frame(
  x=c(0,1,2,3,4,5),
  y=c(0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.3, 0.1)
  )

plot(NULL, xlim=c(0, 6), ylim=c(0,1), xlab="x", ylab="f(x)")
polygon(
  x=c(dta_example$x[1], dta_example$x, dta_example$x[length(dta_example$x)]),
  y=c(0, dta_example$y, 0),
  col="red"
  )
points(dta_example, pch=16)
```

How would I go about using the above to produce an empirical probability distribution that I could then characterise in terms of mean, sd, skewness, kurtosis etc? Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the use `approxfun` on your data. Also, I would add 0s to your data beforehand:

```
dta_example <- rbind(c(0,0), dta_example, c(0,0))
```

1. First create a function corresponding to your data

   ```
   f <- approxfun(dta_example$x, dta_example$y)
   ```
2. Compute numerically the $n$-th moment

   ```
   n <- 3
   xmin <- min(dta_example$x)
   xmax <- max(dta_example$x)
   m <- integrate(function(x) x^n*f(x), lower=xmin, upper=xmax)
   m
   # 47.1216 with absolute error < 0.002
   ```

---

EDIT: An example with a simple triangular distribution.

```
dat <- data.frame(x = c(-1, 0, 1), y = c(0, 1, 0))
f <- approxfun(dat$x, dat$y)
```

1. Plot of the distribution

   ```
   plot(f, xlim=c(-2,2), col="red") ; grid()
   ```

[image: Triangular Distribution]

2. Check that the integra between -1 and +1 is equal to one

   ```
   integrate(f, lower=-1, upper=+1)
   ```
3. Compute mean and variance

   ```
   integrate(function(x) x*f(x), lower=-1, upper=+1)
   integrate(function(x) x^2*f(x), lower=-1, upper=+1)
   ```